# Singleton property not updating during "OnClicked" event

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, properties

I'm sure I remember this being a threading issue, but I can't find an answer.  It seems like it should be simple.  I have the following code:

```
    private void Dingle_Clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        dynamic doc = ScraperBrowser.Document;
        string htmlText = doc.documentElement.InnerHtml;
        htmlText = htmlText.Replace("\r\n", " ");

        Regex targetStart = new Regex(this works just fine);
        MatchCollection target = targetStart.Matches(htmlText);

        string priceData = target[0].Value; 

        foreach (StorePriceData spData in Lists.Singleton.MedicineList[medIndex].Prices)
        {
            Regex rx = new Regex(spData.StoreName + @".+?(\$\d+\.\d+)");
            MatchCollection matches = rx.Matches(priceData);
            if (matches.Count > 0)
            {
                if (matches[0].Groups.Count > 0)
                {
                    spData.MedicinePrice = matches[0].Groups[1].Value;
                }
            }
        }

        string cookie = Application.GetCookie(new Uri("https://www.goodrx.com"));
        ++medIndex;
        ScraperBrowser.Navigate(Lists.Singleton.MedicineList[medIndex].GoodRxUrlString);
    }
```

The problem I'm having is that the spData.MedicinePrice takes the value, but the value in the singleton "MedicineList" is not being updated.  How can I make that value update?

The singleton code:

```
public class Lists
{
    private static Lists _singleton;
    public static Lists Singleton
    {
        get
        {
            if (_singleton == null) _singleton = new Lists(); return _singleton;
        }
    }

    public List<MedicineInfo> MedicineList {
        get
        {
            return new List<MedicineInfo>()
            {
                new MedicineInfo() { Name = "ZOLPIDEM TAB 10MG", Doses = "30 tablets" },
                new MedicineInfo() { Name = "PANTOPRAZOLE TAB 40MG", Doses = "30 tablets" }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

MedicineInfo class code:

```
public class MedicineInfo
{
    public MedicineInfo()
    {
        Prices = new List<StorePriceData>()
        {
            new StorePriceData() { StoreName = "xxxx" },
            new StorePriceData() { StoreName = "yyyy" },
            new StorePriceData() { StoreName = "zzzz" },
        };
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Doses { get; set; }
    public List<StorePriceData> Prices { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks!

Carl

Comment: Why would this be a threading issue? How is the singleton implemented?

Comment: I don't actually _know_ that it's a threading issue.  Since this is WPF, I believe that events happen outside of the UI thread, and that there is something that needs to be done to update UI thread properties from event threads, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: No, the UI events are executed on the dispatcher thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are returning a new `List<MedicineInfo>` each time the getter of `MedicineList` is called.

Also, `Lists` is not really a singleton. A better implementation would look something like this:

```
public sealed class Lists
{
    private static readonly Lists _singleton = new Lists();

    private readonly List<MedicineInfo> _medicineList = new List<MedicineInfo>
    {
        new MedicineInfo() { Name = "ZOLPIDEM TAB 10MG", Doses = "30 tablets" },
        new MedicineInfo() { Name = "PANTOPRAZOLE TAB 40MG", Doses = "30 tablets" }
    };


    private Lists() { }

    public static Lists Singleton => _singleton;

    public List<MedicineInfo> MedicineList => _medicineList;
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  That should have been more obvious to me than it was.